flutter MediaQuery does not detect device size well
I use final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; and    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; for my width and height of Widgets such as SizedBox and Container.
When I use one device to make the sizes, for example screenHeight*0.1 it fits well. But when I bring in a different device it gives me an overflow. I have to keep adjusting the coefficient until both fit perfectly.
What can I do so that when I make the sizes, it fits well with all device. Because, let's face it, I don't know which device my user will be using.
I tried it on both physical and virtual devices

Stop using MQ for this! use LayoutBuilder for breakpoints, and Flex (Row/Column) for layout. Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

You should use MediaQuery to define the size that the widgets must occupy in the screen. If you have widgets that must fit that size, you can use the FittedBox widget, that makes its content to fit its parent.

I think you are facing problem to show some sized Box or container according to height and width of device. So you can use Expanded widget. You can wrap widget with Expanded so that it can occupy required space.
If you provide you code so I can understand better.

You are probably using MediaQuery incorrectly.
MediaQuery: Gives you the available space of the full screen, while full screen means that MediaQuery will ignore all the content and just gives you the height and weight of your device screen.
LayoutBuilder: Gives you the remaining available space of a certain area. That means that it will take into consideration the widgets that you already have, for a common example, the AppBar.
So if your screen size is h=1920p, w=720p and your Appbar takes 300p of height. Assuming that want to get the height inside the body with an appBar:

Using mediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height => 1920p (the max height of    the device)
Using LayoutBuilder => constrains.maxHeight => 1920p - 300p = 1620p

